# Blackboard Bold in bbm package

Tags: pdftex, blackboard

The link over here http://cs.brown.edu/about/system/managed/latex/doc/bbm.pdf says

> By typing \mathbold or \mathversion{bold} you switch to the bold
> variant of some math symbols.

But when i type \mathbold, I always get an error. Can someone please help with the commands to generate blackboard "bold" fonts using the bbm package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve found an error in the `bbm` manual.  They meant `\boldmath`, a standard command to select `\mathversion{bold}`.  So, you could set your title formatting to `\bfseries\boldmath` or `\fontseries{bx}\mathversion{bold}\selectfont`.  This would give you bold math symbols to match your bold text.

A more-convenient way to select the bold version of a single math symbol is the `\boldsymbol` command from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, bm, bbm}

\newcommand\mathbb[1]{\mathbbm{#1}}
\newcommand\mathbbb[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbb{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \mathbb{N}\mathbbb{N} \\
  \mathbb{R}\mathbbb{R} \\
  \mathbb{C}\mathbbb{C} \\
  \mathbb{Q}\mathbbb{Q}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image: mathbbm sample]

This aliases the `bbm` commands to more-standard ones used by other packages, such as `mathalpha`.

You can switch to sans-serif by changing the definition of `\mathbb` to

```
\newcommand\mathbb[1]{\mathbbmss{#1}}
```

Which gets you

[image: bbm sans-serif font sample]

Note that the `bbm` fonts are in an obsolete format, and will be pixelated in a PDF file.  If you want bold double-struck letters, you can load an OpenType math font with a bold version in `unicode-math` (such as Libertinus Math or XITS Math), and `\boldsymbol{\mathbb{N}}` will work.  In PDFTeX, you can load

```
\usepackage[bb=pxtx]{mathalpha}
```

This supports `\mathbbb{N}` if you select a `\mathbb` font that comes in bold, and will get you a Type 1 outline font instead of a bitmap.

Comment: Many thanks for the kind help.

Comment: How about the sansserif bold? Could you please be kind enough to add the command line for that also?.

Comment: @crskhr OK, done.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the kind help :)